# CraftBukkit Plugin Coding Error

Tags: java, eclipse, minecraft, bukkit

I am making a simple `/heal` Bukkit plugin for `CraftBukkit Beta Build 1.7.2 R0.3`.  (I'm new to java.) I am programming in Eclipse.  I'm  getting an error that says:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
public boolean onCommand_heal(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String commandLabel, String[] args){
    Player player = (Player) sender;
    if(commandLabel.equalsIgnoreCase("heal")){
        if(args.length == 0){
        player.setHealth(20);
        player.setFireTicks(0);
        player.sendMessage(ChatColor.GOLD + "You are healed!"); 
        }else if(args.length == 1){
            if(player.getServer().getPlayer(args[0]) !=null){
                Player targetPlayer = player.getServer().getPlayer(args[0]);
                targetPlayer.setHealth(20);
                player.sendMessage(ChatColor.GOLD + "Player Healed!");
            }else{
                player.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "PLAYER NOT ONLINE!");
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try doing this:

```
Player targetPlayer = Bukkit.getServer().getPlayer(args[0]);
//or this:
Player targetPlayer = plugin.getServer().getPlayer(args[0]);
```

instead of

```
Player targetPlayer = player.getServer().getPlayer(args[0]);
```

and the same thing here, replace:

```
if(player.getServer().getPlayer(args[0]) !=null){
```

with:

```
if(Bukkit.getServer().getPlayer(args[0]) != null){
```

Also, you should always use `floats` when setting health since a recent Bukkit update. `setHealth(int)` is deprecated, and replaced with `setHealth(float)`, so try:

```
targetPlayer.setHealth(20.0f);
```

Comment: Thanks.  It was the float issue

Comment: Your comment about replacing `player.getServer()` with `Bukkit.getServer()` is irrelevant and actually can be frowned upon depending on the coding style.
@mas0701 make sure you check that commandsender instanceof Player before casting, as right now if you run that command from the console you'll get a nasty error.

Comment: @Tips48 I really see no reason to frown upon `Bukkit.getServer()`as opposed to `player.getServer()`, and `plugin.getServer()`... The only difference is that `Bukkit.getServer()` is static, and adding onto your comment about checking if `sender instanceof Player`, you might also want to make an `else` statement that would send the sender a message like *Only players can heal themselves* so they know why nothing is happening

Comment: I agree with your second point @jojodmo, and I was just saying that because I know there were points where they were considering removing `Bukkit`.  Granted, I haven' used Bukkit in over a year, but you get the point.